# looping on Value of Column in Talend

Tags: talend

I have a scenario. In One of my Master Job 3 Child Job will run. Now after Each Child Job On SubJobOk in toraclerow an update will run to update status in Database for that Particular Table based upon Maximum(Update_Date). In next tOracleInput I am selecting the status of the Table which ran in the First Child Job and passing to that tjavarow where I am passing that Status Value to a Context.

From tjavarow using RunIF condition I am triggering the 2nd ChildJob. Now I am using the RunIF Condition like context.status.equals("Y"). Now I want to do a negative testing where I want to loop based upon some iteration to check for some time whether Status Value changed to N to Y.

My Job Design is like this now:

```
ChildJob1---OnComponentOk---toracleRow(UpdateRunning to change status from N to Y)---OnComponentOk---toracleinput(selecting the status of the table related to ChildJob1)---->tjavarow(Passing the STATUS Value to context)--------RunIF(context value equals "Y")----->ChildJob2
```

I want to loop now whether the status is still N. It will check whether Status changed to Y or not. Zero Byte file based option can't be taken.

Comment: I don't get your question. Did you try with tLoop ?

Comment: No.Can you tell me what needs to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want; if you want to loop on a child job until a flag is set by it, you can do this :

```
tLoop (while context.status.equals("N"))-- Iterate -- tRunJob (childjob) -- row -- tJavaRow (context.status = row.status)
```

inside the `tLoop`, set loop type as `While`, and in Condition, type `context.status.equals("N")` (and clearing Declaration and Iteration boxes).

Your child job passes the status to the calling job using a `tBufferOutput` which has a single column `status`. Then the tRunJob needs to have the same schema as the tBufferOutput, and the checkbox "`Propagate the child result to the output schema`" checked. The status returned by the child job is then assigned to `context.status`. On the next iteration, `tLoop` either continues looping if `context.status` is equal to "`N`" or stops if it's "`Y`".
To ensure you child job runs at least once, `context.status` needs to be set to "`N`" first.